# how to host angular2 application in IIS?

Tags: angular

I have quickstart project of Angular2. currently I am running my application using command "npm start".

I want to host my application in IIS.

I created a website in IIS and given physical path to my quickstart folder. Now I am getting error "System" is not defined.

I have "system.config.js" file in my "src" folder. application works when I use "npm start" but doesn't work when I access using IIS "http://localhost/quickstart/src"  url.

Comment: Where specifically are you getting that error?  What page are you loading?  What code does that page reference and execute?

Comment: I download project as per the instruction given on this url https://angular.io/guide/setup. Now I want to host this solution in IIS.

Comment: I wouldn't use the quickstart, i'd use angular-cli   when you are ready you type ng build --prod  and it will put your finished application in a /dist/ folder.  from there you can just copy that folder into your IIS web root and it will work

Comment: Yes I can go for anguarcli but I have already added new pages in quickstart application. It would be extra work to go for angularcli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed below steps to host application in IIS.
1. build angular application using ng build --prod
2. copy dist folder to a new folder
3. created virtual directory for this new folder in IIS.

it worked.